# Is it possible to downgrade RVM version without uninstalling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I have two servers that are running (almost) identical installs. Both servers are VMs and server_b was created as a copy of server_a (this is how I know they are identical installs). Server_a has since been updated using 'rvm get HEAD'.

server_a:

- rvm version 1.15.4
- ruby-1.8.7-p334
- .rvmrc file specifying ruby-1.8.7@my_gemset (no patch level specified)
- Rails 3.0.5

server_b:

- rvm v 1.2.8
- ruby-1.8.7-p334
- .rvmrc file specifying ruby-1.8.7@my_gemset (no patch level specified)
- Rails 3.0.5

When I deploy to server_a, RVM complains that ruby-1.8.7-p370 is not installed, but deploying to server_b does not generate this error. I'm not sure why it is looking for the latest patchlevel for 1.8.7 -- I have gone through the RVM configs on each server, comparing them. (The output from 'rvm info' results in the same information from both servers, other than the RVM version).

I've come to the conclusion that it might have to do with the version of RVM? Have I missed something obvious? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should rather update then downgrade, you real problem is that you specify ruby version without patchlevel, in this case RVM will take the latest known patchlevel, so instead of `rvm use 1.8.7` you need to tell it `rvm use 1.8.7-p334`.

As for the downgrade question you can specify version `rvm get 1.2.8`, just keep in mind this version is about 2 years old, a lot of things was fixed in rvm since then, and you will not get any support for the old version.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. You can do it. 
Previously i was using rvm version 1.29.0
I tried with this code to use rvm with the version of 1.28.0
Code is : `rvm get 1.28.0`